# Setting default value to a column in Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a Datagridview which I am populating from the DB. There is one column which I want to get updated at runtime with DEFAULT value: like "UPS" to each and every row in that Datagridview.

So far, I have this code:

```
 public void UpdateTransmitStatus(DataTable table)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("update dbo.JobStatus SET ShipMethodTransmitted = 
'UPS' WHERE  JobTableId = @JobTableId ", _mySqlConnec);
            cmd3.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@JobTableId", row["JobID"].ToString()));
            cmd3.Connection = _mySqlConnec;
            _mySqlConnec.Open();
            cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            _mySqlConnec.Close();
        } 

        }
    }
```

Here JobTableId is the PKey which refers to this column. So far its not updating my columns. Any help?

Comment: You say you are loading your DataGridView from the DB but your code suggest it is the other way around.  As far as updating the specific column with the default value 'UPS' it appears that you are already doing that.  Can you clarify what the problem is and what you are doing?

Comment: retag this to C# or something , you will get better response.

Comment: did you check that you are getting valid values for row["JobID"].ToString() , if you are not getting any exceptions then problem could be in the where clause condition

Answer (score 0):

This code is only for Updating 1 specific column. Thats all!

I guess it is running GOOD NOW! Thanks for your comments guys :)